# Is there such a thing as a WordPress console?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm learning how to develop WP plugins.

I would like to try calling some methods to see what they return. It would be great if I could do so in the console instead of writing tests or log messages.

Is there such a thing as a Wordpress console? That is, I'd like to log in to WP in the terminal and call methods directly.

Comment: There's the [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) but this won't allow you to access plugin functions unless the plugin is setup to work with the CLI.

Comment: Thanks. I see the CLI provides `wp shell` which is what I need.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see notices/messages in the admin area, try 'Admin Notices' . See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices .

A good tutorial is here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-admin-notices-in-wordpress/.

I recommend setting the 'is_dismissable' class in the HTML of the message you want to display. That will allow you to close/exit the notice.

Comment: I think this might've been posted in response to the wrong question?

Comment: I saw this as a question about putting admin messages on the screen, rather than in a log file. The OP is writing plugins, so I assumed he would be at a plugin settings screen or the admin area and wanted to see messages from his plugin. Admin notices would be good for that.